# Passing functions between RequireJS files

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I've got a file which needs to run on page load (randomise_colors.js), but also needs to be called by another file as part of a callback function (in infinite_scroll.js). The randomise_colors script just loops through a list of posts on the page and assigns each one a color from an array which is used on the front-end.

Infinite Scroll loads new posts in to the DOM on a button click, but because the randomise_colors.js file has already ran on page load, new content loaded is not affected by this so I need it to run again. I'm open to other suggestions if it sounds like I could be tackling the problem in a different way, I'm no JS expert.

Currently I'm getting Uncaught ReferenceError: randomise_colours is not defined referring this line of infinite_scroll.js:

```
randomise_colours.init();
```

I'm calling all files that need be loaded on document.ready in **app.js**

```
require(['base/randomise-colours', 'base/infinite-scroll'],
    function(randomise_colours, infinite_scroll) {

            var $ = jQuery;

            $(document).ready(function() {

                infinite_scroll.init();
                randomise_colours.init();

            });

    }
);
```

This is **infinite_scroll.js** which initialises Infinite Scroll and features the callback. The callback function runs whenever new items are loaded in via AJAX using the [Infinite Scroll jQuery plugin](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll). I've put asterix around the area where I need to run the randomise_colors.init() function from randomise_colors.js.

```
define(['infinitescroll'], function() {

    var $ = jQuery,
        $loadMore = $('.load-more-posts a');

        function addClasses() {
            **randomise_colours.init();**
        };

    return {

        init: function() {
            if($loadMore.length >= 1) {
                this.setUp();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        },

        setUp: function() {
            this.initInfiniteScroll();
        },

        initInfiniteScroll: function() {
            $('.article-listing').infinitescroll({
                navSelector  : '.load-more-posts',            
                nextSelector : '.load-more-posts a',    
                itemSelector : '.standard-post'          
            }, function(newItems) {
                addClasses();
            });

            //Unbind the standard scroll-load function
            $(window).unbind('.infscr');

            //Click handler to retrieve new posts
            $loadMore.on('click', function() {
                $('.article-listing').infinitescroll('retrieve');
                return false;
            });
        }

    };

});
```

And this is my **randomise_colors.js** file which runs fine on load, but needs to be re-called again after new content has loaded in.

```
define([], function() {

    var $ = jQuery,
        $colouredSlide = $('.image-overlay'),

        colours = ['#e4cba3', '#867d75', '#e1ecb9', '#f5f08a'],
        used = [];

        function pickRandomColour() {

            if(colours.length == 0) {
                colours.push.apply(colours, used);
                used = [];
            }
            var selected = colours[Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length)]; 
            var getSelectedIndex = colours.indexOf(selected);
            colours.splice(getSelectedIndex, 1);
            used.push(selected);

            return selected;
        };

    return {

        init: function() {
            if($colouredSlide.length >= 1) {
                this.setUp();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        },

        setUp: function() {
            this.randomiseColours();
        },

        randomiseColours: function() {
            console.log('randomise');
            $colouredSlide.each(function() {
                var newColour = pickRandomColour();
                $(this).css('background', newColour);
            });
        }

    };

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to reference randomiseColours inside the infiniteScroll file. So you need to change your define function to the following:

```
define(['infinitescroll', 'randomise-colours'], function(infiniteScroll, randomise_colours)
```

Remember that when using require you need to reference all variables through the define function, otherwise they will not be recognised.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. Unfortunately the randomise_colours function doesn't appear to be picking up on the newly added content but I guess this is a separate issue.